# Cant mute tab with firefox JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Beginner and never used JS before so dont really know what im doing but im trying to make a firefox extension that minimizes and mutes a window for a few minutes and cant get the tab to mute, but everything else works. Below is what i have so far. its just an edited version of the window-manipulator sample from firefox.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // const query = opts => new Promise(resolve => chrome.tabs.query(opts, resolve));
  function getCurrentWindow() {
  return browser.windows.getCurrent();
  }
  if (e.target.id === "window-Start1") {
    browser.tabs.getCurrent().then((currentTab) => {
      browser.tabs.update(currentTab.id,{muted: true});
      console.log(CurrenTab.mutedInfo.reason,currentTab.mutedInfo.extensionId)
    });
    getCurrentWindow().then((currentWindow) => {
      browser.windows.update(currentWindow.id,{state: "minimized"});
    });
    setTimeout(max,75000);
    // setTimeout(max,500);
  }
  if (e.target.id === "window-Start2") {
    browser.tabs.getCurrent().then((currentTab) => {
      browser.tabs.update(currentTab.id,{muted: true});
    });
    getCurrentWindow().then((currentWindow) => {
      browser.windows.update(currentWindow.id,{state: "minimized"});
    });
    setTimeout(max,180000);
  }
  if (e.target.id === "window-Start3") {
    browser.tabs.getCurrent().then((currentTab) => {
      browser.tabs.update(currentTab.id,{muted: true});
    });
    getCurrentWindow().then((currentWindow) => {
      browser.windows.update(currentWindow.id,{state: "minimized"});
    });
    setTimeout(max,900000);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

ive tried taking lines from other extensions that mute tabs and im not sure what goes wrong.
for example:   `// Apply state to tab browser.tabs.update(tab.id, {muted: state}) console.log(tab.mutedInfo.reason,tab.mutedInfo.extensionId)`
the muting part happens before the minimizing and the minimizing works, so it doesnt seem broken but just wrong. idk.

Thanks for your help